# What are the MAPI properties that hold message Body

Tags: c++, window, outlook-addin, mapi

AFAIK, message body is stored in either of the following properties - PR_RTF_COMPRESSED or PR_BODY or PR_BODY_HTML but on my system when I see through the outlook spy - I don't find any of these properties in IMessage object yet message body is fine. Is there is any other property which holds the message body ? I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the message is saved when you look at it with OutlookSpy (I am its author) - especially if you do that in a new message inspector.
Outlook commits the changes to the MAPI system only when the message is saved.

Also keep in mind for the `ReportItem` object, the `Body` property is constructed dynamically from various properties in the recipient table, there is no regular body.

Comment: I am checking the messages in Inbox which means message is already saved.

Comment: In outlook options when I changed the mail settings of 'When sending messages in Rich Tech format to Internet recipients' to "Send using outlook Rich Text format" then I see the PR_BODY_W and PR_RTF_COMPRESSED properties are set.